# Elementary lower bounds for $n^{1/n}$

Tags: inequality, elementary-functions

I can show that
$n^{1/n} > 1+1/n$
for integer $n \ge 3$
by completely elementary means - 
no logs, exponentials,
or calculus.

Are there better bounds that
can be proved in an elementary way?

Here is my proof:

The bound is equivalent to
$n > \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}$
or
$\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}} < 1$.

For $n=3$,
this is $\frac{4^3}{3^4} 
=\frac{64}{81}
< 1$.

The ratio of consecutive terms is

$\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+2}}}{\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}}
&=\frac{(n(n+2))^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{2n+2}}\\
&=\frac{(n^2+2n)^{n+1}}{(n^2+2n+1)^{n+1}}\\
&< 1
\end{align}
$

so the terms are decreasing
and thus less than $1$.

Of course, since $e^x > 1+x$,
$n^{1/n} = e^{\ln n/n} > 1+\ln n/n$,
but this is non-elementary.

Comment: What's non-elementary about $e^x \ge 1 + x$?

Comment: In what sense are you not using exponentials when you evaluate the expression $n^{1/n}$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan $n$th power is just repeated multiplication and then $\sqrt[n]x$ is just the supremum of all $y$ with $y^n<x$. This is at least somewhat less than summoning an eigenfunction of differentiation ...

Comment: @Hagen: I don't understand why you would be willing to define $\sqrt[n]{x}$ that way and then not be willing to define $e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^n$, which is enough to prove the second bound marty states and which is also more or less optimal.

Comment: My feeling is that since it is easy to understand $x^n$, it is not to hard to understand its inverse, without talking about limits. The definition of $e^x$ is harder to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!\cdot n^k}$$
After cancelling $n!$ against $(n-k)!$ we are left with $k$ factors $\le n$ in the numerator. Since we have $k$ factors $=n$ in the denominator, we have $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!\cdot n^k}\le \frac1{k!}$. This brings us almost to the series $\sum \frac 1{k!}$ for $e$, but remains elementary enough, I guess. All but the $0$th summand are $\le \frac12$, so we get the very weak $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\le 1+\frac n2$, hence for $n> 2$
$$\sqrt[n]n>\sqrt[n]{1+\frac n2} \ge 1+\frac1n.$$

Of course, we can easily improve this by noting $\frac1{k!}<\frac1{2^{k-1}}$ for $k\ge1$ and hence $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n<3$.
This makes
$$ \sqrt[n]n\ge\sqrt[n]9> \left(1+\frac1n\right)^2=1+\frac2n+\frac1{n^2}\qquad \text{for }n\ge 9$$
and so on.